# Change direction and move an element through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to move the "pin" in the 2D array. The pin needs to change the direction first, north, south,etc and only then move forward. There are 2 functions, change direction to the left, to the right and move forward.
And the currentPosition should be able to show the position the pin is in. The travelLog should keep track of where the pin has been in. The instruction, I would like to give is something like ( "lrrlf")

```
let pin = {
  direction : 'N',
  travelLog : []
  };
let currentPosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0  
};




function turnLeft(pin) {
  
  switch (pin) {
    case 'N':
      pin.direction = 'W';
    break;
    case 'S':
      pin.direction = 'E';
    break;
    case 'E':
      pin.direction = 'N';
    break;
    case 'W':
       pin.direction = 'S';
    break;     
  
  }
  return pin.direction;
  
}

function turnRight(pin) {
    
  switch (pin) {
    case 'N':
      pin.direction = 'E';
    break;
    case 'S':
      pin.direction = 'W';
    break;
    case 'E':
      pin.direction = 'S';
    break;
    case 'W':
       pin.direction = 'N';
    break;     
  
  }
  return pin.direction;
  
  
}

function moveForward(pin) {
  
  
  switch (pin) {
      
    case 'N' :
      currentPosition.x = x--;
      break;
    case 'S' :
       currentPosition.x = x++;
    case 'W' :
        currentPosition.y = y--;
    case 'E' :
         currentPosition.y = y--;      
    
  }
  
  return curentPosition;
  
  
}

function commands(command) {
  
 for(let i = 0; i < command.length; i++ ) {
  let comando = command[i]
  switch (comando) {      
   
    case 'l' :
    turnLeft();
    break;
      
    case 'r' :
    turnRight();
    break;
    
    case 'f' :
    moveForward();
    break;
   }
   return comando;
   rover.travelLog.push(currentPosition);
   console.log(travelLog);
   
 } 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: The code doesn't work. I would like to know what is wrong with it. If this is the right approach to it.

Comment: First explain the problem. You should not ask to fix your code. This is not a good practice.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a clear problem statement. Provide input, the output you get, and the output it should have given.

Comment: I call the function for ie :  command(rrf) . It should turn the pin right, right again and then move forward. But after that I print the currentPosition and the pin continues on x:0 y:0. The position that the pin has started. Trincot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're pushing references to the same `currentPosition` object every time. When you modify the object, all the array elements contain that modification.

You need to make a copy of the object when you push it into the `travelLog` array:

```
travelLog.push({...currentPosition});
```

`return commando;` statement ends the function, so nothing after that will be executed. You should return after the loop is done, but you can't return `commando` because it's a local variable inside the loop. There's not really any need to return anything specific from `commands()`.

And there's no `rover` variable, so `rover.travelLog` should just be `travelLog`.

```js
function commands(command) {
  for (let i = 0; i < command.length; i++) {
    let comando = command[i]
    switch (comando) {
      case 'l':
        turnLeft();
        break;
      case 'r':
        turnRight();
        break;
      case 'f':
        moveForward();
        break;
    }
    travelLog.push(currentPosition);
  }
  console.log(travelLog);
}
```